# Codeigniter Email Class Error

Tags: php, codeigniter, fwrite, fgets, fsockopen

I can send e-mail in my local server using following codes,

```
    $config['protocol'] = 'smtp';
    $config['charset'] = 'UTF-8';
    $config['mailtype'] = "html";
    $config['wordwrap'] = TRUE;

    $config['smtp_host'] = $this->config->item('smtp_host'); // smtp.critsend.com
    $config['smtp_user'] = $this->config->item('smtp_user'); 
    $config['smtp_pass'] = $this->config->item('smtp_pass');
    $config['smtp_port'] = $this->config->item('smtp_port'); // i'm tried 587 and 25

    $this->load->library('email');
    $this->email->initialize($config);
    $this->email->from('test@test.com', 'test');
    $this->email->reply_to('test@test.com', 'test');
    $this->email->to($user['email']);
    $this->email->subject($subject);
    $this->email->message($html);
    $this->email->set_newline("\r\n");
    $this->email->send();
```

But it isn't work on real server. I'm getting this error,

> Message:  fsockopen() [function.fsockopen]: unable to connect to smtp.critsend.com:25 (Connection timed out)
>
> Filename: libraries/Email.php
>
> Line Number: 1689
>
> Message:  fwrite(): supplied argument is not a valid stream resource
>
> Filename: libraries/Email.php
>
> Line Number: 1846

Some answers for this error, "activate php_openssl". But i'm not using ssl (and i cant).

Comment: It is not able to connect to your email server. Did you tried logging in with the credentials you are using to send your email.

Comment: Maybe it is a firewall port issue?